# PIC 18 controller as serial to ethernet bridge

Tags: windows, serial-port, microcontroller, ethernet, microchip

I am planning to use PIC18F6*** serial microntroller for my project serial-ethernet converter. Once I will put my hex code in PIC micro-controller for send recieve serial port data I will use the windows hyper-terminal and for checking the ethernet data is there any application in windows?

If my question is not clear I am ready to explain it better... please let me know.....

Comment: You should clarify a little better the technologies you will use. For instance, how will the microcontroller appear to Windows? As a serial, or as a network device? Would you be using NDIS, or some other interface, etc.

Comment: is this a tcpip or udp on the ehternet port?  Is this ASCII test over the ethernet and serial port?

Comment: My micro-controller is PIC18F67J60. I am using MPLAB IDE with C18 C compiler. My new device will be having 2 ports one is ethernet and other is serial. One TCP server will be running on this. The serial port on device will be connected to window machine's usb port using serial to USB converter and the ethernet port on device will be connected to window machine ethernet port by cross-cable. Now for Tx/Rx data on serial port i will use serial port. But for Tx/Rx ethernet data I m looking for an application on windows. The microcontroller will appear to windows as another machine as client/server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper Terminal, or Tera Term; assuming this is just a simple text based exchange from the TCPIP port to the serial port.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to use Wireshark to view the ethernet data going between your PC and the micro for troubleshooting